# How to save each and every clicked button action in json file/object using angularjs or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I wanted to save each and every button action(for ng-clicked and non-ng-clicked including file uploads/urls i.e. whatever I click, that button should be stored in json file/object i.e. for all `<input type="button">` in my case.) in my json file/object using either angularjs or jquery ? How can I do it ? Created    [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/6qm7jeo3/10/),Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
html:
```

Comment: Have a look around for something called "Command Pattern". That will allow you to 'record' actions (and more).

Comment: Thanks Marvin Smit, Unfortunately I don't know that, anyway I will check into that, Could I have any links or example of it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add global beforeSend handler using:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
    var data = {
       url: settings.url,
       data: settings.data
    };
    $.ajax({url: 'save_json.php', data: data, beforeSend: $.noop);
  }
});
```

This will work only for ajax requests, if you want to log form submit you will need to add global submit handler:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'save_json.php',
    data: {url: $target.attr('action')},
    beforeSend: $.noop, 
    sucess: function() {
      $target.submit(function(e) {
        // prevent global handler
        e.stopPropagation();
      }).submit();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @jcubic for your reply, Can I know how can i do this in my example please ?

Answer (score 1):

Set click listener on the form element.

```
$('#formid').click(function (e) {
    //e.target will give the element clicked inside the form
});
```

Check if the e.target is a button element and save the button in your json file/object.

Comment: Thanks @varun for your reply, Can I know how can i do this in my example please ?

Comment: Hi @Dhana, I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6qm7jeo3/12/ . I don't know the exact structure of JSON you need. I have added a scope variable called userActions, which is an array of JSON. Each JSON in userActions array has the event type and element informations. Look at the logs in the console to see userActions array.

Comment: Hi varun, Thanks for your replay and sorry for my late reply, as I have updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/o1bt6pfk/1/, here each and every action should store in my json object/file, i have given my required sample json structure here too, kindly let me know that how to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most angular-way of achieving this is to create a directive and use this directive instead of `<input type="button">` I created a sample;

```
var actionLogs = [];

yourModule.directive("actionButton", [function () {
return {
    scope: {
        action: '&',
        type: '@'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {

        var logClickEvent = function ($event) {
            var log = {element: $element, action: $scope.action, clickTime: new Date()};
            actionLogs.push(log);
        };

        $scope.doAction = function ($event) {

            //** Do whatever you want here before every action
            logClickEvent($event);

            $scope.action.apply(null, []);
        };
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (typeof attrs.type === "undefined") {
            scope.type = "button";
        }
    },
    template: '<input type="{{type}}" ng-click="doAction($event)"><span ng-transclude></span></input>'
};
}]);
```

You can use `<action-button action="yourNgClickFunc()">` instead of `<input type="button" ng-click="yourNgClickFunc()">` and your clicks will be logged in the array `actionLogs`.

In some cases you may want to log click events other then `<input type="button">`s. Then I prefer to use an attribute directive instead of element directive, for example;

```
var actionLogs  = [];

yourModule.directive("loggable", [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.click(function (e) {
            var action = scope[attrs.ngClick.split("(")[0]];
            var log = {element: element, action: action, clickTime: new Date()};
            actionLogs.push(log);
        });

    }
};
}]);
```

You can use `<input type="button" ng-click="yourNgClickFunc()" loggable>` instead of `<action-button>` and your clicks still will be logged in the array `actionLogs`